# Add Change Event Handler to New Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How do I add a change event handler to a newly inserted sheet? Basically, I have a button that copies a hidden template sheet and insert it as a new sheet. However, the event handler does not copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the [Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx) event of each Worksheet separately. Thus, after inserting a new one you need to subscribe to the event.

```
worksheet.Change += WorksheetChangeEventHandler;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the ".change".